# How to pass pk of detail view into fk of form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Good afternoon, I am fairly new to Django and I am not sure how to go about this.I have a Django 2.2 project with these models:

```py
class Equipment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
            max_length=15,
            unique=True,
            verbose_name='asset name')
    asset_cat = models.ForeignKey('category',on_delete=models.PROTECT,verbose_name='asset category')
    asset_loc = models.ForeignKey('location',on_delete=models.PROTECT,verbose_name='asset location')
    state = models.ForeignKey('status',on_delete=models.PROTECT,verbose_name='status')

    brand = models.CharField(
            max_length=15,
            unique=False,
            blank=True)

    model = models.CharField(
            max_length=12,
            unique=False,
            blank=True,
            verbose_name='model number')

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.name)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('equipment-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['asset_cat', 'name']
        verbose_name_plural = 'pieces of equipment'


class Action(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey('equipment',on_delete=models.PROTECT,verbose_name='asset name',blank=False)

    dt = models.DateTimeField(
            auto_now_add=True,
            verbose_name='date and time of incident')

    incident = models.TextField(
            blank=True,
            null=True)

    CHANGE = 'CHANGE'
    SERVICE = 'SERVICE'
    ACTION_CHOICES = (
            (CHANGE, 'CHANGE'),
            (SERVICE, 'SERVICE')
    )

    act = models.TextField(
            blank=True,
            choices=ACTION_CHOICES,
            null=True,
            verbose_name='action taken')

    act_detail = models.TextField(
            verbose_name='action detail',
            blank=False)

    result = models.TextField(
            blank=True,
            null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('service-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-dt']
        verbose_name_plural = 'service calls'
```

I have an Equipment Detail View like this:

```py
class EquipmentDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Equipment
    template_name = 'equipment_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EquipmentDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        return context
```

The detail view has two buttons: edit and service. If I click edit I have a model form that allows me to edit that instance of the Equipment model successfully.
However, when I click the service button, my form comes up to create an instance of the Action model, but when I submit it tells me that the null value in name_id violates the not null constraint.
It looks like my question is, how can I pass equipment.id from the Equipment Detail view to action.name of the action create form and keep the service button concept?

Action Form:

```
class ServiceForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Action
    fields = ['incident', 'act_detail', 'result']
```

Action (actually service) view:

```
class EquipmentServiceView(generic.CreateView):
template_name = 'equipment_service.html'
form_class = ServiceForm
queryset = Action.objects.all()
```

Comment: Can you post your Action form and view for processing?

Comment: Added the Service Form and Service view. Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to go with simpliest solution to include `name` in form fields and have urls setup as:
`/equipment/<id>` - equipment detail view
`/service` - service (or action) create view

There are several ways of passing equipment id:

**1) From url**
We are going to change url to accept equipment_id. That means instead of `/service` you will have url `/equipment/<equipment_id>/service`.
Probably best solution - you will use URL according to REST architecture and will have very clear structure. Client can access page from anywhere (like just copy paste link from mail) and it will work.

urls.py:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('equipment/<int:pk>', EquipmentDetailView.as_view(), name='equipment-detail'),
    path('equipment/<int:equipment_pk>/service', EquipmentServiceView.as_view(), name='service-create')
]
```

Your service button should look like this: `<a href="{% url 'service-create' object.pk %}">service</a>`

and finally your view:

```py
class EquipmentServiceView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'equipment_service.html'
    form_class = ServiceForm
    queryset = Action.objects.all()

    def form_valid(self, form):
        equipment_pk = self.kwargs['equipment_pk']
        equipment = get_object_or_404(Equipment, pk=equipment_pk)
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.name = equipment
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

**2) Session data**
In case you want to preserve service url without adding equipment_id, you can store equipment id either in [session](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/) data(on your server) or in cookies(on client). That's not exactly good - client have to go to `EquipmentDetailView` prior to creating `Service`, but this will keep your urls intact.

views.py:

```py
class EquipmentDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Equipment
    template_name = 'equipment_detail.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        response = super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        request.session['last_equipment_pk'] = self.object.pk
        return response


class EquipmentServiceView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'equipment_service.html'
    form_class = ServiceForm
    queryset = Action.objects.all()

    def form_valid(self, form):
        equipment_pk = self.request.session.get('last_equipment_pk')
        equipment = get_object_or_404(Equipment, pk=equipment_pk)
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.name = equipment
        self.object.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

P.S.: `name` is bad field name for `ForeignField` - should be something like `equipment` or so. Those labels usually associate with `CharField` and expected to be strings.

Comment: This is great. Thanks for the response. I think this is the right track. I had to make an adjustment with my get_absolute_url for the Action model, but everything looks amazing. Nice detail: my problem is fixed And I learned something. Well done, sir.

Comment: P.S.> I used solution 1 and it was great!